# "Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated." But there is a call back

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, raspberry-pi3, deprecation-warning

I have a function that will handle the on-off state of pins based on the documents in a database. This function uses a lot of libraries and I believe that one of these is causing the deprecation (based on the deprecation tracking I included below my code snippet I think it is the OnOff Gpio Library for Raspberry PI). Which function is causing the deprecation? What would be the disadvantage to rolling back on the update of Node? I would really like to hear some opinions on this, Thank you in advance.

---

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
        var collection = db.collection('re');//change as needed
        collection.findAndModify(
        {"restart":"sensor","value":false},
        {},
        {"$set":{"value":true}},
        {},
        function(err,result){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            else{
                console.log(result);
                if(result.value!=null){
                    spin.write(0);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        spin.write(1);
                    },10000);
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Sensor should stay on");
                    spin.write(1);
                }
            }
        });


    }
    db.close();
});
```

---

> (node:10503) DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function
>   without callback is deprecated.
>
> at maybeCallback (fs.js:98:42)
>
> at Object.fs.write (fs.js:703:16)
>
> at Gpio.write (/home/pi/node_modules/onoff/onoff.js:190:6)
>
> at Object. (/home/pi/local-opio/final:16:6)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
>
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
>
> at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
>
> at run (bootstrap_node.js:422:7)
>
> at startup (bootstrap_node.js:143:9)
>
> at bootstrap_node.js:537:3

Comment: It looks like `spin.write` is the culprit.

Comment: just pass `Boolean` as a callback if you don't care about the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have 3 calls to the `onoff` package's [write function](https://github.com/fivdi/onoff#writevalue-callback) without optional callbacks. Try passing an appropriate callback (that takes an `err` argument) to each of those calls.

Comment: You were right! I checked the libary and the write function has the option for callbacks. I added them and I don't get the error anymore. Thanks a bunch!! spin.write(1,function(err){}); Is the write function I use now.